# Issue connecting to SSL using VeriSign G5

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, paypal, amazon-ec2

I have been struggling with this for days and have searched for days. I am trying to connect to `api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443` from my AWS EC2 instance. The instance is Windows Server 2012 R2. I have installed openssl to try and debug. Under Trusted Root Certification Authority I can see `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 7/16/2036` in there. I also have openssl installed on my development machine.

If I run `openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443` in the development machine it returns with a `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`. If I run that same line in the EC2 instance, it returns with a `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

I then downloaded the G5 certificate that reads:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIE0zCCA7ugAwIBAgIQGNrRniZ96LtKIVjNzGs7SjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
>   yjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQL
>   ExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJp
>   U2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxW
>   ZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0
>   aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwHhcNMDYxMTA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMzYwNzE2MjM1OTU5WjCByjEL
>   MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZW
>   ZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJpU2ln
>   biwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxWZXJp
>   U2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9y
>   aXR5IC0gRzUwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCvJAgIKXo1
>   nmAMqudLO07cfLw8RRy7K+D+KQL5VwijZIUVJ/XxrcgxiV0i6CqqpkKzj/i5Vbex
>   t0uz/o9+B1fs70PbZmIVYc9gDaTY3vjgw2IIPVQT60nKWVSFJuUrjxuf6/WhkcIz
>   SdhDY2pSS9KP6HBRTdGJaXvHcPaz3BJ023tdS1bTlr8Vd6Gw9KIl8q8ckmcY5fQG
>   BO+QueQA5N06tRn/Arr0PO7gi+s3i+z016zy9vA9r911kTMZHRxAy3QkGSGT2RT+
>   rCpSx4/VBEnkjWNHiDxpg8v+R70rfk/Fla4OndTRQ8Bnc+MUCH7lP59zuDMKz10/
>   NIeWiu5T6CUVAgMBAAGjgbIwga8wDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
>   BAMCAQYwbQYIKwYBBQUHAQwEYTBfoV2gWzBZMFcwVRYJaW1hZ2UvZ2lmMCEwHzAH
>   BgUrDgMCGgQUj+XTGoasjY5rw8+AatRIGCx7GS4wJRYjaHR0cDovL2xvZ28udmVy
>   aXNpZ24uY29tL3ZzbG9nby5naWYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFH/TZafC3ey78DAJ80M5+gKv
>   MzEzMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCTJEowX2LP2BqYLz3q3JktvXf2pXkiOOzE
>   p6B4Eq1iDkVwZMXnl2YtmAl+X6/WzChl8gGqCBpH3vn5fJJaCGkgDdk+bW48DW7Y
>   5gaRQBi5+MHt39tBquCWIMnNZBU4gcmU7qKEKQsTb47bDN0lAtukixlE0kF6BWlK
>   WE9gyn6CagsCqiUXObXbf+eEZSqVir2G3l6BFoMtEMze/aiCKm0oHw0LxOXnGiYZ
>   4fQRbxC1lfznQgUy286dUV4otp6F01vvpX1FQHKOtw5rDgb7MzVIcbidJ4vEZV8N
>   hnacRHr2lVz2XTIIM6RUthg/aFzyQkqFOFSDX9HoLPKsEdao7WNq
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

And on the EC2 instance I ran the following: `openssl s_client -CAfile g5.cer  -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443` and the response was `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

So when I pass in the certificate to openssl, it works fine. But when it tries to find it in the keystore it fails.

I followed these instructions to install the certificate: http://www.sqlservermart.com/HowTo/Windows_Import_Certificate.aspx

Can anyone provide assistance to lead me in the right direction? Is there something specific I need to do with AWS?

--- Edit. Here is the output after attempting to change the policy

```
C:\>openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(0000013C)
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGiDCCBXCgAwIBAgIQSmPFPGKFy6vVcS32CMWsdDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB+
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEdMBsGA1UEChMUU3ltYW50ZWMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xHzAd
BgNVBAsTFlN5bWFudGVjIFRydXN0IE5ldHdvcmsxLzAtBgNVBAMTJlN5bWFudGVj
IENsYXNzIDMgU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQSAtIEc0MB4XDTE2MDExNDAwMDAwMFoX
DTE4MDExNDIzNTk1OVowgYwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIDApDYWxpZm9y
bmlhMREwDwYDVQQHDAhTYW4gSm9zZTEVMBMGA1UECgwMUGF5UGFsLCBJbmMuMRow
GAYDVQQLDBFQYXlQYWwgUHJvZHVjdGlvbjEiMCAGA1UEAwwZYXBpLTN0LnNhbmRi
b3gucGF5cGFsLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANXB
QRl1wRXByqGLGt64dqkOJ8srJSPcqYwjA+KL3JuSmWKgvHUKg581H5p6/aX5BD92
ZmMLMrE3gtQnQU9cfatkw7+sFNtDDXh4gJhNAWz1Mw7VuDTRzk4N0YcO55Wy2WQ4
/Z2fYHfL6IoohXfqtYdFY1JzOXkqunPfhsSOKTb03Lf2k4hniwoMVsn8rOSBklNZ
6knC4iiaEOpo/EGtYylbpnoRg1aQP+1Oyc+bwG1LPT64XZA/4frcm1gKnFYBYtRM
RKBmQsF88SjSNUP9DiriHiD8tXryy2xAoQml+bfkslb5FJYLP7xmncQaXQRk/YUo
ehdW8Git3BQpwNZS9f0CAwEAAaOCAvEwggLtMCQGA1UdEQQdMBuCGWFwaS0zdC5z
YW5kYm94LnBheXBhbC5jb20wCQYDVR0TBAIwADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwHQYD
VR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMGEGA1UdIARaMFgwVgYGZ4EMAQIC
MEwwIwYIKwYBBQUHAgEWF2h0dHBzOi8vZC5zeW1jYi5jb20vY3BzMCUGCCsGAQUF
BwICMBkaF2h0dHBzOi8vZC5zeW1jYi5jb20vcnBhMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFF9gz2GQ
Vd+EQxSKYCqy9Xr0QxjvMCsGA1UdHwQkMCIwIKAeoByGGmh0dHA6Ly9zcy5zeW1j
Yi5jb20vc3MuY3JsMFcGCCsGAQUFBwEBBEswSTAfBggrBgEFBQcwAYYTaHR0cDov
L3NzLnN5bWNkLmNvbTAmBggrBgEFBQcwAoYaaHR0cDovL3NzLnN5bWNiLmNvbS9z
cy5jcnQwggF/BgorBgEEAdZ5AgQCBIIBbwSCAWsBaQB2AN3rHSt6DU+mIIuBrYFo
cH4ujp0B1VyIjT0RxM227L7MAAABUkI8Bj4AAAQDAEcwRQIhAIHuCBevjKTfgyu3
p69luk4DBTOJjBozTsnJIs+dVS7NAiASjAaBPD/bGWGXC8bayAREXvuPSr0W+xU0
l0T6Kaje9wB3AKS5CZC0GFgUh7sTosxncAo8NZgE+RvfuON3zQ7IDdwQAAABUkI8
Bn8AAAQDAEgwRgIhAPIWGT/KdSkWSlR3SzPA6O+sP16mpF9Mc/8BBKhAck0WAiEA
u/ie0GvZ8wctdK8OhOnOUUQvQ8njBqd7l5s2GfRWymMAdgBo9pj4H2SCvjqM7rko
HUz8cVFdZ5PURNEKZ6y7T0/7xAAAAVJCPAZmAAAEAwBHMEUCIHkB7wZfWQPm+ZCP
cUAOQwutIiMSXmKFUM9GiHzJ72VoAiEAh+44zz2mRc/NcwTvQsW1BQcjL12y8gji
UBJgtrlwZq4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAEKkutMm4VqebHi49Zw35dFStnRb
RD9sUIpFvuvSCTnvM0uwFGHa01hoH6XCk0mQf7Hlv8eUjQCYEjq/yOy/qd1D/0FG
pG5QYXpiiB1rfJyGSTps6TMsSzhGJwZt6e7ZNJ29uGBvfaYi5S+qbxqUkEUIOoeE
+K77MUD5ouwN6mm3azvemVMoJEPwjbVUZZwfLlxBQbwX4C2Kdihrn/r+AkeYiLej
Q+1pdnXz9Hwj3SM+uZWpu8f7kbczSWsuQmSV4gparNkOTjk5TwJvyrS3z+DQW674
FdfkrYmxqiiaELhsMPhRyjKce5HA2ol1GsnJ0IJCPjJc2o40IiL1AL552eA=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3524 bytes and written 423 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 9E01CD86FA9CB07DAD505F17E34C099B2E4C8B85126C68DCF2946F8859FF6435
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 4BF94BD3EBEE701226ABD3B2344F6B325F21218761D755B02EA6B00FE90866396A9A317A59729D166A1B970AD8D3903B
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1455312915
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Here is a screenshot of my settings:
[image]

Comment: W2012R2 ships with the G5 cert pre-installed in the TRCA folder.  Follow the steps in [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731638.aspx) to ensure that Third-Party Root CAs are trusted under the Stores tab.

Comment: @gboda Thanks for the assistance, I made that change and attempted to re-run the openssl command. I have edited my question with the response. Any ideas?

Comment: The SSL v3 certificate of `api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com` was signed with an _intermediate certificate_ (Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - **G4**) that needs to be installed in the W2012 Cert Store. G4 was issued by the Symantec G5 self-signed CA cert.
So the cert chain goes like this:  paypal -> Symantec/VeriSign G4 Intermediate -> G5 Root.

Use the Symantec SSL Checker tool to view the cert chain. [link](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to develop your app with OpenSSL lib, instead of using the trust store built into the Win Server OS *(as the default trust store in a operating system may not always be up to date)*, there's an alternative to build the trust store from Curl project [HERE](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) (Curl provides a regularly-updated conversion in Privacy-Enhanced Mail (PEM) format from Mozilla, which you can use directly, and the Verisign Root package including G5-G4-G3 root certs are contained as well for this case)

A few more steps to check on your OpenSSL,

1. Check where your OpenSSL cert bundle is stored, run `openssl version -a`
   , and it would report the directory used:

   ```
   OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
   built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
   platform: Cygwin-x86_64
   options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
   ...
   OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/ssl"
   ```

   Check the directory of `OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/ssl"` and look for `certs` dir under that

*You may also check the version here to make sure 1.0.1e or above is installed to support TLSv1.2, which is another piece of the PayPal API endpoints upgrade requirements*

2. Replace the `tls-ca-bundle.pem` with what you downloaded from Curl project (the Mozilla cert bundle)

Answer (score 0):

your openssl returns the following:

```
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

that means you do not have Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4 installed in your certificate store, you can download the certificate from [here](https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=INFO2045) and install it or just copy the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```